# What are the grammar rules that support using participle clauses in this way (that is, the way they were used in the sentences below)?

Tags: participle-clauses

> The North West of England has seen the greatest percentage increase in first-time buyer prices, **rising by 35% (£43,812) over five years to 2021**.
> Source: independent.co.uk

> Local fixed line calls were the highest throughout the period, **rising from 72 billion minutes in 1995 to just 90 billion in 1998**.

I have seen many sentences like these ones on the news, so I'm sure the above sentences are correct. My problem is that I don't know why: I read that participle clauses are used to show result, reason, and concurrency, but the writers of the above sentences didn't use them to do those things.

As far as I am concerned, the writers of those sentences just used participle clauses to add additional information.

Comment: Yes, participle clauses commonly show *result, reason and concurrency*, but those aren't the rule for their use. The rule for their use relates to which grammatical structures can participle clauses replace. The semantic function of those grammatical structures is irrelevant. Lambie's answer shows which structure the participle clause replaced in your example sentence.

Comment: Surely it's expressing concurrency, saying what the rise was in the period? Why don't you think that?

Answer (score 0):

"Local fixed line calls were the highest throughout the period, rising from 72 billion minutes in 1995 to just 90 billion in 1998."

is the same as:

"Local fixed line calls were the highest throughout the period and they rose from 72 billion minutes in 1995 to just 90 billion in 1998."

To avoid making a compound sentences, writers often use participle clauses. They also sound better, very often.

Comment: It's too bad about poor dvts.